# Why the word "BEHANCE" appears in my title in the Google results

Tags: seo, google

I have customised one of the internal pages of my site in Wordpress YOAST SEO plugin for a specific title. When I look in Google the results shows only the first part of my title followed by "- behance". I have no idea what this is. Any help?

Comment: What is the title tag text? Also, what is the domain name? This should be remarkably easy to answer.

Comment: Thanks closetnoc. The URL is http://runnerbeantours.com/private-tours-barcelona and the title tag: "Private Tours Barcelona - Runner Bean"

Comment: BTW Nice looking site! I will poke around to see if there any clues outside of the answer given. I will have to do this when I get back. I will have more options available on my laptop. Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help :-). It is all sorted now (I just changed the text and it shows OK now). Still a mistery why "Behance" appeared as I have never used it before.

Answer (score 1):

The title can be different from the one put in title tag at times, based on how google generates the titles of its results, as explained here:
https://yoast.com/google-page-title/

Checked your site specific results :
https://www.google.co.in/#q=inurl:http://runnerbeantours.com/

`behance` does appear in few of the results.

But for your page, this is not the case,as the google cache (april 9 )of those pages does not have "behance" in the title or anywhere in the page.

view-source:http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:v8ub-fXBVWMJ:runnerbeantours.com/private-tours-barcelona/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in

The possibility is that it might have been in the title of your pages sometime back, perhaps due to any `behance` brand wordpress theme or plugin being used then.